# Polarion OpenAPI: setTestSteps

Tags: javascript, polarion

I'm trying to write a script that sets some fields in the testSteps table from other values I already have, and I can't figure out the format. When I do a `workItem.getTestCase().getTestSteps();` on the item I get back

```
keys:[step, description, classification, sampleParameters, duration, instructions, expectedResult, notes, labLocation, sampleDesc];steps:[{values=[text/html:
 1, text/html:
, text/html:
, text/html:
, text/html:
, text/html:
, text/html:
, text/html:
, text/html:
, text/html:
]}];
```

How would I say, change the first testSteps value of step from 1 to 3 and then set it back?

Comment: Can you maybe find it in the documentation? Or do you have a link to it?

Comment: @Klaassiek here you go: ITestStep https://almdemo.polarion.com/polarion/sdk/doc/javadoc/com/polarion/alm/tracker/model/ITestSteps.html

Answer (score 2):

TestSteps are basically a two dimensional array of text objects.
As it seems, you are using a customized config for the Steps and Polarion sent you the first line of the teststep-field with first element ("step") pre-filled as "1" and the other fields (most probably) empty.
The Text Objects can be displayed with `".getContent()"` method.

For setting Teststeps you need to construct this nested list of lists (for every step you need a list with the same number (9 in your example) of Textobjects, the first element is a number)